# UK Visa Refused, Please Help in Reapplying ( Will Appreciate Your Kind Response )

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have a good Travel history ( Visited UAE Twice , Italy , Spain , USA Twice , also Visit UK Last year on a Family Visit Visa Which was Sponsored by my Brother ) Now this time I apply for UK General Visitor Visa with my Family ( Wife & 2 Kids ) , to Visit UK for Tourism for 10 Days, But Unfortunately Refused because I have Transactions of almost 6-8 Lac in my Bank Account in month of June & I didn't explain the Origin of Funds, Now I want to tell you guys that this amount is a Commission which I get from my Company every 6 months, I got around 8 Lac in February as well ( Which is Deposited in my Bank Account as well ) for last 6 months of 2015 & Now in June I got again almost 8 Lac for first 6 months of 2016, Now my Question is How Can I prove that this is my Commission, ( Note, When I apply my UK Visa, I clearly Mention That I also got commission from my Company except Salary but I did not mention amount & dates ), Now Please Guide me that Should I Reapply immediately by explaining all this situation ? How Can I Prove that this amount is my commission for last 6 months ? Please Help me , I will really Appreciate your kind response. If Possible Please give me a Sample  that How to Write a Letter to Visa Officer When Reapplying after Refusal to explain the above Mention Situation. & Please also tell me that id it fine if my employer explain on Company's Latter head that they give me Commission of last six months in June., I will be grateful for your kind Response.

[image: REFUSAL LETTER]

Comment: This will probably be closed as a duplicate, but as a quick note: if this money indeed comes from your employer, you should have no problem demonstrating that; an official letter from them should probably do.

Comment: Another quick note: If you do reapply with a written explanation, you **really** ought to get someone with a better grasp of written English than you to work over that explanation. The way you have written your question here (with completely random capitalization, erratic punctuation, spurious spaces scattered around the punctuation and no paragraph breaks) makes it very hard to read, which is likely to put an ECO in something of a bad mood. They're probably _supposed_ not to let such communication problems influence the decision, but they're also human and it's a chance not worth taking.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74584/cover-letter-when-reapplying-after-uk-visa-refusal